# Can I use a helper method in a redirect method call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using Rails 5 and I am trying to use [this redirect_back method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/redirecting.rb#L88).

However, my issue is that I am using it for a `Comment#Create` which can be called for both a Question & Answer object. So depending on which it is, I want it to redirect back to that respective object (which have two different routing paths ofcourse).

So, what I have done is created a concern, added a custom method and then attempted to call that method in the `redirect_back` call but it doesn't seem to be working.

The concern looks like this:

```
module CommentRedirect
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

def question_or_answer(comment)
  if comment.commentable_type.eql? "Question"
    question_path(comment.commentable)
  elsif comment.commentable_type.eql "Answer"
    question_path(comment.commentable.question)
  end
end

end
```

Then my `Comment#Create` looks like this:

```
format.html { redirect_back(fallback_location: question_or_answer(@comment)), notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
```

The error I get is this:

```
SyntaxError at /comments
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting '}'
... question_or_answer(@comment)), notice: 'Comment was success...
...
```

Given that this is the `redirect_back` code in Rails:

```
def redirect_back(fallback_location:, **args)
  if referer = request.headers["Referer"]
    redirect_to referer, **args
  else
    redirect_to fallback_location, **args
  end
end
```

Can I use the helper method in the way I am attempting?

If not, how else can I achieve what I want to do?

**Edit 1**

This is the entire `Comment#Create` method:

```
  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
    @comment.user = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_back(fallback_location: question_or_answer(@comment)), notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @comment }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: My guess is that there is a syntax error somewhere above the line that you posted (Comment#Create). Can you post that entire file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't notice right away either, but your line is not valid syntax:

```
format.html { redirect_back(fallback_location: question_or_answer(@comment)), notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
```

It should be this:

```
format.html { redirect_back(fallback_location: question_or_answer(@comment), notice: 'Comment was successfully created.') }
```

Comment: Perfect. This is what I needed. A 2nd set of eyes. Thanks!